# Como fijar intervalos de 15 minutos en un DateTimePicker de c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, oledb

Tengo una conexion al banco de datos de Access con OleDb y dos campos datetimepicker con hora de inicio y fin en formato time. No se como poder lograr que cada uno de esos campos me muestre la hora cada 15 minutos asi 10:00; 10:15; 10:30;10:45; etc. Si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradeceria montones.

Comment: Hola Andrea, ¿qué has intentado? ¿Puedes poner tu código?

Comment: no evaluaste utilizar dos controles NumericUpDown, este control permite definir el intervalo de incremento, pones uno para la hora y el otro para los minutos

Comment: @Kiko_L. Hola. No lo puse porque solo habia intentado cosas con el dateTimePicker y Combobox pero no funcionaban.

Comment: @Leandro. No no sabia sobre esa función voy a inverstigar sobre ella y  a porbar me ahorraría mucho si funciona. Gracias por el dato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es necesario que agregues tu codigo para modificarlo

en tu clase defines:

```
private DateTime prevTimePicker1;
private bool navigatingDateTimePicker = false;
```

dentro del contructor de tu clase

```
prevTimePicker1 = dateTimePickerStart.Value;
navigatingDateTimePicker = false;
```

Agregas el siguiente evento:

```
private void dateTimePickerStart_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!navigatingDateTimePicker) {


    navigatingDateTimePicker = true;


    TimeSpan tempTS = dateTimePickerStart.Value - dateTimePickerStart.Value.Date;
    TimeSpan roundedTimeSpan;

    TimeSpan TDBug = dateTimePickerStart.Value - prevTimePicker1;
    if (TDBug.TotalMinutes == 59)
    {
        // saltando una hora en el control
        roundedTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15 * Math.Floor((tempTS.TotalMinutes - 60) / 15));
        dateTimePickerStart.Value = dateTimePickerStart.Value.Date + roundedTimeSpan;
    }
    else if (dateTimePickerStart.Value > prevTimePicker1)
    {
        // se redondea al intervalo
        roundedTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15 * Math.Ceiling(tempTS.TotalMinutes / 15));
        dateTimePickerStart.Value = dateTimePickerStart.Value.Date + roundedTimeSpan;
    } else {
        // para el valor previo
        roundedTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15 * Math.Floor(tempTS.TotalMinutes / 15));
        dateTimePickerStart.Value = dateTimePickerStart.Value.Date + roundedTimeSpan;
    }
    navigatingDateTimePicker = false;
  }
  //se actualiza el valor.
  prevTimePicker1 = dateTimePickerStart.Value;
}
```

Comment: Miguel Zarate! Muchas gracias nunca hubiese llegado a esa solución rapido. Había intentado cosas con el DateTimePicker. AddMinutes pero me faltaba el bucle... por eso no me funcionaba.